# Silex Micro Framework: Run from a subfolder

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, silex

I download Silex because I want to try it in my next project. I'm using mamp under Windows 8.1 64x , I think that this doesn't matter but, anyway, I put Silex into C:\mamp\htdocs\projectfolder\ `(http://locahost/projectfolder/)`

This means that I got `http://locahost/projectfolder/vendor` and `http://locahost/projectfolder/web/`

I wrote this .htaccess under "web" directory

Options -MultiViews

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /projectfolder/web
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

It works perfect if I come into `http://locahost/projectfolder/web/hello`, but I want to come from /projectfolder/, so I created a new htaccess file in /projectfolder with this content:

Options -MultiViews

```
RewriteEngine On
#RewriteBase /projectfolder
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ web/index.php [L]
```

But when I run it, the app retun an NotFoundException: Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

I'm new to silex too, so if anyone has better insights please tell/teach us :)

I decided to create a project on a separate folder from silex and, what I did was, I created a new index.php requiring silex's autoload.php and a new .htaccess which is basically the same.

So, I have this structure:

```
/myproject/silex/
/myproject/app/
/myproject/app/index.php
/myproject/app/.htaccess
```

my .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -MultiViews

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

and my index.php

```
<?php
require_once __DIR__.'/../silex/vendor/autoload.php';
...
```

BTW, I configured a vhost to point to /myproject/app/

Hope this helps.

Comment: ok, I also managed to get this work fine, I am using AMPPS stack now, in which we can create custom domain easily(like MAPP PRO, so no need to edit VHost), so now it is working with basic configs. But now new issue, in my twig template i am not able to get app.request.getbaseurl function. I dont know why, I am just following their docs.